# onActivityCreated from an ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-actionbaractivity

So I have an ActionBarActivity that hosts a ListFragment, an editText, and a button. I was setting the button's onClickListener in the onCreate method for this activity, however, when clicking the button, I used the ListFragment's getListView method. However, I wound up getting IllegalStateExceptions, so I realized that I need to set the onClickListener in the the onActivityCreated method, instead of onCreate.

The problem is that I can't seem to override the onActivityCreated method. Android Studio keeps telling me that I'm not overriding any methods, and I can't override it from the alt+insert menu.

I do need to keep this activity as an ActionBarActivity, so I can't switch to a FragmentActivity or anything, but I'm really not sure what to do. I know FragmentActivities are an ancestor of ActionBarActivities, so I thought I should be able to override onActivityCreated.

Comment: extend fragment or fragmentactivity then use getActivity() as a context

Comment: The Button is in the activity. And as I said, I need to keep it an ActionBarActivity for now.

Comment: Ok, show your code.  It's hard to tell what's going on from just the description.

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: ActionBarActivity is depricated. Use AppCompatActivity with toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out the issue seemed to be a misguided attempt to reload the fragment in the activity's onResume method. Getting rid of that seemed to fix everything. Still a little strange that I couldn't extend onActivityCreated, but everything is working now.

Comment: `onActivityCreated` is for Fragments, not Activities.